# Where is MACAddress in MSFT_NetAdapter?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

The [documentation for Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx) tells us that:

> The Win32_NetworkAdapter class is deprecated. Use the MSFT_NetAdapter
>   class instead.

However, the [documentation for MSFT_NetAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968170(v=vs.85).aspx) lacks a `MACAddress` property.

So what is the correct way for getting the `MACAddress`?

Comment: I don't know how this is run in c# in order to answer, BUT, running the powershell shows me that the `PermanentAddress` property returns an unformatted MAC address (`AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF` in `ipconfig -all` VS `AABBCCDDEEFF` in `MSFT_NetAdapter`)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks! That might be it. Though `Win32_NetworkAdapter` has both. And their description is different than one another.

Comment: Yep, they differ a lot in fact. But I didn't see anything else close to my MAC in that class